# Elasticsearch - query_string with wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I have some text in elastic search containing urls in various formats (http://www, www.) what I want to do is to search for all texts containing e.g., google.com.

For the current search I use something like this query:

```
query = { "query": {
                "bool": {
                     "must": [{
                            "range": {
                            "cdate": {
                                "gt": dfrom,
                                "lte": dto }
                            }
                        },
             { "query_string":{
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "default_field": "text",
                "analyze_wildcard":"true",
                "query": searchString } }
            ]
        }
        }}
```

But a query looking like *google.com* never returns any result, searching for e.g., the term "test" works fine (without "). I do want to use query_string because I'd like to use boolean operators but I really need to be able to search substrings not only for whole words.

Thank you !

Comment: what is the mapping of your url fiedl?

Comment: "text" is just a text field.

Answer (score 1):

It is true indeed that `http://www.google.com` will be tokenized by the standard analyzer into `http` and `www.google.com` and thus `google.com` will not be found.

So the standard analyzer alone will not help here, we need a token filter that will correctly transform URL tokens. Another way if your `text` field only contained URLs would have been to use the [UAX Email URL tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html), but since the field can contain any other text (i.e. user comments), it won't work.

Fortunately, there's a new plugin around called [analysis-url](https://github.com/jlinn/elasticsearch-analysis-url) which provides an URL token filter, and this is exactly what we need (after a [small modification](https://github.com/jlinn/elasticsearch-analysis-url/issues/2) I begged for, thanks [@jlinn](https://github.com/jlinn) ;-) )

First, you need to install the plugin:

```
bin/plugin install https://github.com/jlinn/elasticsearch-analysis-url/releases/download/v2.2.0/elasticsearch-analysis-url-2.2.0.zip
```

Then, we can start playing. We need to create the proper analyzer for your `text` field:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "url_host": {
          "type": "url",
          "part": "host",
          "url_decode": true,
          "passthrough": true
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "url_host": {
          "filter": [
            "url_host"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "url": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "url_host"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

With this analyzer and mapping, we can properly index the host you want to be able to search for. For instance, let's analyze the string `blabla bla http://www.google.com blabla` using our new analyzer.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/urls/_analyze?analyzer=url_host&pretty' -d 'blabla bla http://www.google.com blabla'
```

We'll get the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "blabla",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 0,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "bla",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 0,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "www.google.com",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 0,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "google.com",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 0,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "com",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 0,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "blabla",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 0,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 5
  } ]
}
```

As you can see the `http://www.google.com` part will be tokenized into:

- `www.google.com`
- `google.com` i.e. what you expected
- `com`

So now if your `searchString` is `google.com` you'll be able to find all the documents which have a `text` field containing `google.com` (or `www.google.com`).

Comment: @pinas Were you able to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

Full-text search is always about exact matches in the inverted index, unless you perform a wild-card search which forces traversing the inverted index. Using a wildcard at the beginning of your queryString will lead to a full-traverse of your index and is not recommended.

Consider not just indexing the URL, but also the domain (by stripping off protocol, subdomain and any information following the domain) applying the [Keyword Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html#analysis-keyword-tokenizer). Then you can search the domains against this field.

Comment: HI - I might have explained this bad. What I do is to index posts from a company internal wiki (actually the comments) and try to make these searchable. One query that I'd like to execute is to find all pastebin links that were ever mentioned in these comments. So I do not index only the urls but full text comments which might contain pastebin links. 

In the future I'd like to do queries like "all comments that contain a pastebin link and the word 'test engine' " - query string seems fine but this boolean operations but wildcards are not working.