# Elasticsearch - search URL

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have `www.nike.com` indexed, I want:

- Search `www.nike.com`, return `www.nike.com`
- Search `nike.com`, return `www.nike.com`
- Search `http://www.nike.com`, return `www.nike.com`
- Search `http://nike.com`, return `www.nike.com`

One option is to use default analyzer, when build index for `www.nike.com`, manually generate its all variations: [`www.nike.com`, `nike.com`, `http://www.nike.com`, `http://nike.com`] and index all of them. Then search anyone of them will `www.nike.com`.

I'm not sure whether there is more graceful solution for this?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887458/elasticsearch-query-string-with-wildcards/34986008#34986008

Comment: have a look https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html. It might help