# How to construct Elasticsearch to filter only URL with subdomain?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I store URL as a field in Elasticsearch. However, I would like to filter only documents that has subdomain in the `url`.

For example.

I want my search result to have

```
http://any-subdomain.example.com
```

But I don't want the result to have

```
https://www.example.com
```

Is this possible in Elasticsearch query?

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887458/elasticsearch-query-string-with-wildcards/34986008#34986008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `query_string` query? For example, I used for twitter data like below:

```
GET /twitter2/tweet/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "entities.media.url",
           "query": "https\\:\\/\\/t.co\\/* AND -https\\:\\/\\/t.co\\/6*"
        }
    },
    "_source": ["entities.media.url"]
}
```

For this search my mapping :

```
PUT /twitter2/tweet/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "entities": {
            "properties": {
                "media": {
                    "properties": {
                        "url": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use following query for your case:

```
GET /your-index/your-type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "url",
           "query": "http\\:\\/\\/*.example.com AND -http\\:\\/\\/www.example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

> Note : you should know that you can get your result faster if you use something to handle while indexing your data as `url` and `host`. With elastic 5.x, you can use ingest node to manipulate your data like this. I will try to create a pipeline for this but you can check [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/ingest.html) for more information