# elasticsearch sub domain search doesn't match correctly

Tags: elasticsearch

We use elasticsearch to index content from the net. 
The content is very likely to contain links to other websites.
The problem is elasticsearch index domains as a single word.
When querying google.com the search doesn't yield a document with the string www.google.com

I would like to be able to match all documents against a query for a domain and sub domain.

One solution I found is to extract all urls into another field and use the path hierarchy analyzer.

But is there another solution that doesn't require this? I would rather www.google.com would be indexed as three different words (Use the dot as a token) and use parentheses around my query like this:"google.com"

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887458/elasticsearch-query-string-with-wildcards/34986008#34986008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch - query\_string with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887458/elasticsearch-query-string-with-wildcards)