# Elasticsearch Query Returning Zero Results for Substring

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I created my first AWS ElasticSearch cluster and uploaded some data to it (shown below).

When I search for a domain such as `example.com`, I get zero results.

Is this a search query or indexing issue?

```
# curl -XGET -u username:password 'https://xxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/hosts/_search?q=example.com&pretty=true'
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I confirmed that a `match_all` query does return all the records.

**match_all**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "hosts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "KK0PcnMBqk4TBzxZPeGU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "mail.stackoverflow.com",
          "type" : "a",
          "value" : "10.0.0.3"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "hosts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "J60PcnMBqk4TBzxZPeGU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "ns1.guardian.co.uk",
          "type" : "a",
          "value" : "10.0.0.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "hosts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Ka0PcnMBqk4TBzxZPeGU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "test.example.com",
          "type" : "a",
          "value" : "10.0.0.4"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Bulk Upload Command**

```
curl -XPUT -u username:password https://xxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_bulk --data-binary @bulk.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**bulk.json**

```
{ "index" : { "_index": "hosts" } }
{"name":"ns1.guardian.co.uk","type":"a","value":"10.0.0.2"}
{ "index" : { "_index": "hosts" } }
{"name":"mail.stackoverflow.com","type":"a","value":"10.0.0.3"}
{ "index" : { "_index": "hosts" } }
{"name":"test.example.com","type":"a","value":"10.0.0.4"}
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887458/elasticsearch-query-string-with-wildcards/34986008#34986008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the [Path hierarchy tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html#analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer) that takes a hierarchical value like a filesystem path, splits on the path separator, and emits a term for each component in the tree.**

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "path-analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "path-tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "path-tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": ".",
          "reverse": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "path-analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API**

In the index mapping above,`reverse` is set to `true` which will emit the tokens in reverse order. (`reverse` is by default set to `false`)

```
POST /hosts/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "path-analyzer",
  "text": "test.example.com"
}
```

This will produce three tokens:

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "test.example.com",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 16,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "example.com",
        "start_offset": 5,
        "end_offset": 16,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "com",
        "start_offset": 13,
        "end_offset": 16,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    }
]
```

}

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "hosts",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "d67gdHMBcF4W0YVjq8ed",
    "_score": 1.3744103,
    "_source": {
      "name": "test.example.com",
      "type": "a",
      "value": "10.0.0.4"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @A_B did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ?